# PostgreSQL 9.4 Archive Logs Not Being Removed

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave

We have a streaming replication environment setup for testing, and for some reason the archive log directory (pg_xlog) seems to be building up.  This has happened twice now.  The last time it happened we simply rebuilt (because it's test) replication.

Can someone help me understand why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Since we are streaming, the data seems to be in sync between the master and slave.

Comment: Is `hot_standby_feedback` enabled? Do you have an `archive_command` or are you only streaming? Is there a `wal_keep_segments` setting enabled? Above all else, *check the log files*. Anything informative?

Comment: hot_standby_feedback is not enabled.  Yes I have an archive_command, although I set to '/bin/true' temporarily so my drive wouldn't fill up.  Yes I have wal_keep_segements set to 512.  What's the safest way to just disable archiving/wal logs and just use streaming?

Comment: Well, did you have more than 512 logs? 512 * 16MB disk used?

Comment: Yes, there are currently 1852 logs in pg_xlog.

Comment: Huh. Odd. Decreasing now that you've effectively disabled archiving?

Comment: It did some because initially there were over 4,000 logs, but it seems to be holding at 1852.

Comment: that may make sense depending on your checkpoint_segments and wal_keep_segments. The issue sounds like failing archiving so check the logs from before you changed archive_command for messages relating to your archiving script.

Comment: I see a lot of "sending incremental file list" followed by "sent 16777216 bytes received 31 bytes ...".  My archive_command is using rsync to send the files to another system (not the slave).  I set up a cron to delete the logs on that machine as it was filing up that system as well.